# JAX-RPC com.sun.xml.rpc.client.BasicService Not Found

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, netbeans, jax-rpc

I'm trying to consume a JAX-RPC WSDL for first time.

Im using Netbeans 8 and Java 1.7, I also include in my Project Libraries JAX-RPC (JWSDP 1.6) which includes `jaxrpc-impl.jar` (wich includes `com.sun.xml.rpc.client.BasicService`)

But I'm getting the error from Netbeans using Tomcat:

```
    public class CalculoService_Impl extends com.sun.xml.rpc.client.BasicService implements CalculoService {
```

This class is a generated class from the wsdl file with Netbeans

Any idea will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally i got the answer

The problem was that i have jaxrpc.jar duplicated in other project wich was into this new one, but other version without BasicService.

I have replaced de library on the other project and everything works!